# From github CLI, how to change from local repo to a repo on a differnt server, to create issue on that repo?

Tags: github, github-cli

I am new to GitHub Command Line Interface (CLI).

From the github command line interface, I'd wanted to create an issue, but mistakingly selected a local repo intead of the repo from which I forked from. **So how can I change from the local repo to the repo from a different server, where I forked and cloned from**, please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: According to `gh issue create --help`, you can use the `-R` (`--repo`) option to specify a remote repository in which to operate.

Answer (score 0):

`gh issue create --web` is an interesting alternative, because by opening the GitHub issue web page, you would immediately realize you are not on the right repository.

As commented, you would need to use the -R option to reference the upstream repository (as opposed to the default one)

Make sure to use the latest gh version though, at least 1.60 or more, since `gh issue create -R` used to ignore issue template before. ([issue 2361](https://github.com/cli/cli/issues/2361))